# Is this electrical circuit solvable?

Tags: analysis, current-source

I am trying to solve a circuit with two current sources.

I1, I2, V1, V2 are known.
R1, R2, R3 are unknown.

I've tried node analysis, but I can only come up with two equations

\$\dfrac{V_2}{R_1} + \dfrac{V_2-V_1}{R_2} = I_1 \tag{1}\$

\$\dfrac{V_1-V_2}{R_2} + \dfrac{V_1}{R_3} = I_2 \tag{2}\$

so I have two equations and three unknowns.. How can I get the third equations?

[image: Diagram is here]

Comment: Try researching "superposition" in relation to electrical circuits.

Comment: Apart from V1 and V2, there is a third node of which you didn't write down the equation yet. Take a good look at the circuit.

Comment: jippie - Yes, the reference node at the bottom. But that doesn't really count, right?

Comment: It matters. It will give you your third equation to solve for your 3 unknowns. Every node matters, just like every mesh matters if you are doing a complete analysis.

Comment: Hm.. you guys are tantalizing me :) this is actually a thermal circuit problem, I am trying to calculate a very simple thermal model for a motor.
So say reference node is V3. Then I have:
(V1-V3)/R3 + (V3-V2)/R1=I1+I2
And since V3=0, then I have the 3d equation?

Answer (score 2):

The third equation is

\$ \dfrac{V_2}{R_1} + \dfrac{V_1}{R_3} = I_1 + I_2 \$

Comment: @Teomat, to elaborate a little, you had the equations for the two nodes between the resistors (V1 and V2).  This is for the bottom rail/node (implicitly GND or 0, or maybe ambient temperature as your comment suggests).

Answer (score 0):

The circuit as given is not solvable. 
The third equation as given by @Rasoul and others is the result of adding eq1 and eq2. And hence is not **independent**.

I was able to solve it only by realizing that I knew something else about the system. I knew that 1/R1 + 1/(R2+R3) = 1/R
R is known as well.
After using MatLab's fsolve function for this non-linear system, I was able to solve for R1, R2 and R3.

without the R constraint, there are infinitely many solutions.